# lim within an array

Tags: math-mode

I'm having trouble getting lim to work inside an array

Here is my code

```
 \begin{align*}
   \lim_{e \rightarrow 0}{e^{A_\epsilon}} =
   \left(
     \begin{array}{cc}
       1 & \lim_{e \rightarrow 0}{\frac{e^\epsilon + e^{-\epsilon}}{2}} \\
       0 & 1 \\
     \end{array}
   \right)
   =
   \left(
     \begin{array}{cc}
       1 & 1 \\
       0 & 1 \\
     \end{array}
   \right)
 \end{align*}
```

My first lim is working correctly, but the second one looks weird. Here is the output of the above code within my larger document:

[image]

I'm kind of new to Latex, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try `\lim\limits_{e\to 0}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the point made by @PrzemysławScherwentl in his answer -- use `\displaystyle` on the upper-right element of the first matrix -- and implementing his suggestion that `\epsilon` rather than `e` should be the variable whose limit is `0`, I would also recommend you use a `\pmatrix` environment instead of `\left(\begin{array{cc} ... \end{array}\right)`. You'll get less-profligate spacing that way.

Oh, and since the expression fits on a single line, I wouldn't use an `align*` environment. Instead, you should use an `equation*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for pmatrix and equation* environments
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{e^{A_\epsilon}} =
     \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & \displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{\frac{e^{\epsilon} + e^{-\epsilon}}{2}} \\[1.5ex]
       0 & 1 \hfill \\
     \end{pmatrix}   =
     \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 1 \\
       0 & 1 \\
     \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 and the next +1 in mind for extending my vocabulary (the word "profligate"). :-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke - :-)  I tend to use "profligate" as a fancy synonym for "wasteful", "loose", and "extravagant". Some of the other synonyms you'll find in a dictionary certainly do not apply in the present context!

Comment: pmatrix, I wish I had known about this earlier! Great answer, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`\displaystyle` does the work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   \lim_{e \rightarrow 0}{e^{A_\epsilon}} =
   \left(
     \begin{array}{cc}
       1 & \displaystyle\lim_{e \rightarrow 0}{\frac{e^\epsilon + e^{-\epsilon}}{2}} \\[9pt]
       0 & 1 \\
     \end{array}
   \right)
   =
   \left(
     \begin{array}{cc}
       1 & 1 \\
       0 & 1 \\
     \end{array}
   \right)
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To tell the truth, there should be `\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}` not `\lim_{e \rightarrow 0}`.